# How to get log from Process.Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, precompiler

I'm going to precompile an asp.net application in my custom c# form. How do i retrieve the process logs and check whether it is a successful process or not?

Here's my code

```
string msPath = "c:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\";
string msCompiler = "aspnet_compiler.exe";
string fullCompilerPath = Path.Combine(msPath, msCompiler);
msPath.ThrowIfDirectoryMissing();
fullCompilerPath.ThrowIfFileIsMissing();

ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo 
{ 
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WorkingDirectory = msPath,
    FileName = msCompiler,
    Arguments = "-p {0} -v / {1}"
        .StrFormat(
            CurrentSetting.CodeSource,
            CurrentSetting.CompileTarget)
};

Process.Start(process);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) to `true` - this will redirect all output to [`Process.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx), which is a stream that you can read to find all output messages:

```
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo 
{ 
   CreateNoWindow = false,
   UseShellExecute = false,
   WorkingDirectory = msPath,
   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
   FileName = msCompiler,
   Arguments = "-p {0} -v / {1}"
            .StrFormat(
              CurrentSetting.CodeSource, 
              CurrentSetting.CompileTarget)
};

Process p = Process.Start(process);
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

You can also use the `OutputDataReceived` event in a similar way to what @Bharath K describes in his answer.

There are similar properties/events for `StandardError` - you will need to set `RedirectStandardError` to `true` as well.

Comment: ProcessStartInfo class doesn't have a method called Start() and StandardOutput()?

Comment: @Martin Ongtangco - No, it doesn't. `Process` does. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo_methods.aspx

Comment: Hi, i'm getting this error but no details to help me out...

"The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: im pretty sure the file exists.

Answer (score 5):

In your source application register for the ErrorDataReceived event:

```
StringBuilder errorBuilder = new StringBuilder( );
reportProcess.ErrorDataReceived += delegate( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e )
{
    errorBuilder.Append( e.Data );
};
//call this before process start
reportProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
//call this after process start
reportProcess.BeginErrorReadLine( );
```

Any error thrown in the target application can write data into this. Something like this:

```
Console.Error.WriteLine( errorMessage ) ;
```