# Seeing console output of a sub process started by a .net application

Tags: c#, .net, process

My application creates a set of sub processes that runs in the background. These processes all have logging both to file and to console. Is it posssible to open up cmd and see the console output of a process after it has been created outside of cmd?

```
    var p = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = path,
                    Arguments = arguments,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                }
            };

    p.Start();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get log from Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296601/how-to-get-log-from-process-start)

Comment: Thanks, I found some of the same information in @Marc Gravells answere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the *console* of the sub-process, but you can *redirect* the output (`stdout` and `stderr`, ideally), and pipe them to your *own* console/display. An example of redirecting stdout of a sub-process is [shown in full on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. To redirect stdout to my own console. Thanks!

Comment: So if I create a process with RedirectStandardOutput = true, is it possible to open cmd and listen in on the ouput?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit I'm not sure what the "open cmd" bit means in there; if you're creating a process, cmd isn't involved at all - it is just your process and the other process, but yes: you can access the three pipes (`stdout`/`stdin`/`stderr`) - but you need to use `UseShellExecute = false` to do this (which is *how/why* you're talking directly to the other process)

Comment: I mean if I open the command prompt on Windows,assuming i know the PID, is there any way to "listen" to a stdout that is being redirected from a running process?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit that's a very different question to talking about a process you spawned; "don't know"

Comment: Ok, that last question was just out of curiosity. Thanks again!